# Call static method in app_code from a compiled dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, app-code

Is there a way that you can call or reference a static method or class in an App_Code folder from a class that is inside a compiled class library referenced as DLL in the bin directory of an ASP.NET web site?

We have an application that needs to reach out to local defined resources from within a compiled class library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way unless you use a reflection based approach. Also pretty sure your class library/dll does not need to reference the ASP.NET web site/Web project which has the App_Code. My suggestion is to create a link file which reference your class contains the static file and use it in your class library.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234